# ojdbc resultSet.next() trigger network communication for next row

Tags: java, spring, oracle, ojdbc

Problem is simple - when I send query from SQL editor, I got result set during 5 sec. When I send same query from java code with OJDBC driver, I got result during 50 sec.

I profile this issue, and I found that problem come from `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor` inside of method `extractData` during call of `rs.next()`. I found, that `rs.next()` trigger network communication with database, so, I'm pretty sure, that ojdbc does not load all result set, but load it partially. My computer and database located far away from each other, and connection established under vpn. So, if I will retrieve all result set by one batch, my program will be executed during 5 sec (as it happen in SQL editor). If it will work as it work now, it will work 50 sec.

Anybody know how to solve this problem? Is it possible to configure ojdbc? Should I pass some special param in ojdbc connection URL? Any reference?

something similar to this come from each `rs.next()`:

```
01700600000358012110-6600600000621120110144-1308867074-614612231449574851485350567685837848481950484948454850455049324948585349585056449555148107685886977667985827122828569326869327639727380807968827977693251501349574851485350564953485051711910352811110768583858273697676797787367797665830-1271251252-63804111831790001203000000000000800110000
```

Comment: Increase the fetch size: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28621

Comment: no luck, same behavior. I use `setFetchSize` on `resultSetObject`

Comment: you should call `setFetchSize()` on the `Statement` object **before** calling `executeQuery()`